# Mui Autocomplete using Array instead of Json

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am trying to replicate the autocomplete MUI example [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/). But instead of using a JSON data structure, I am just passing an Array.

I am trying the following:

```
export default function SearchTutorialArray() {

const top100Films = [
    'The Shawshank Redemption',
    'The Godfather',
    'The Godfather: Part II',
    'The Dark Knight',
    '12 Angry Men',
    "Schindler's List",
    'Pulp Fiction',
    'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King',
    'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly'
];

const options = top100Films.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
        firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,
        ...option,
    };
});

return (
    <Autocomplete
        id="grouped-demo"
        options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
        groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        sx={{width: 300}}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="With categories"/>}
    />
);}
```

I think the main issue is in the line `getOptionLabel={(option) => option}` which makes the function to return this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1,
> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
> 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, firstLetter}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

When changing this line to `getOptionLabel={(option) => option[0]}` the dropdown is working correctly, but only showing the first letter for every film.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following appraoch:

```
const options = top100Films.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
        firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,
        // no spreading ... here
        label: option,
    };
});
```

later:

```
<Autocomplete
        id="grouped-demo"
        options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
        groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
        // read from label attribute
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
        sx={{width: 300}}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="With categories"/>}
    />
```